# How to show imageview as a slider in Horizontalview where it will display as list but focous only on one item

Tags: java, android, xml

[image: Below image is what i am trying to achieve]

i tried Horizontal Scroll view , Horizontal list view (custom lib) . All i can create is a horizontally scrollable images but what i really needed is to swipe one by one images , where a smaller position of other image is also need to visible to user

Answer (score 1):

Many great apps in the store are built using existing code a collaboration one would say.

Everything you need is [here](http://davidschreiber.github.io/FancyCoverFlow/) just import the module into your IDE and make sure to add the dependencies in your build.gradle.

Allways be sure to see if sombody has done the job for you. [Heres](http://blog.gaoqixhb.com/p/54d777f6bcc4f618501a9306) a great list ENJOY.

Answer (score 0):

u can use view pager for that

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/LIndicator"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

Comment: i already tried it but its takes the whole screen , what i am trying is in the above image

Comment: u can adjust android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xml file by setting its height width as per need... i done it by above code and get as u wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Gallery** view to do this exactly which is available in Android SDK.
Gallery is a controller where center image is selected by default.